# REE 187 RuntimeError (symbol table overflow (symbol _one_time_conditions.)):

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, overflow

My web app now crash that by this error:

```
RuntimeError (symbol table overflow (symbol _one_time_conditions...)):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:3
```

Can anyone help to provide solution ?

The version as below:

> ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334)
>   [i686-linux], MBARI 0x8770, Ruby
>   Enterprise Edition 2011.03 Rails 3.0.7

Many thanks

Comment: Here is more information for it : The error will appare after about 1 day from start . And resume normal after restart the web application.

Comment: did you figure out what was the reason? having same trouble here :)

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you mistakenly leave class caching disabled in production.

Your rails config/environments/production.rb should have:

`config.cache_classes = true`

(I spent a long time debugging this ... logging Symbol.all_symbols.size is the key.)